# Data Validation Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, validation

I would like to get the Date of Birth Value in the stored procedure parameter and validate/filter it if its after 1910 and current year -18 yrs. If it is not then i want to pass/insert the null value. Here is my stored proc without any validation:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CARS_IS_WU_T_INSERT](


           @DOB                           [DATETIME],
           @SSN                           [VARCHAR](9),
           @OCCUPATION                    [VARCHAR](30),
           @PLACE_OF_ISSUANCE             [VARCHAR](30),
           @Exception_Bit                 [BIT])
AS
INSERT INTO [DBO].[UA_T]
         (
          [DOB],
          [SSN],
          [OCCUPATION],
          [PLACE_OF_ISSUANCE],
          [EXCEPTION_BIT])
  VALUES     (
  @DOB,
          @SSN,
          @OCCUPATION,
          @PLACE_OF_ISSUANCE,
          @Exception_Bit)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function `CheckDate` like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CheckDate]
(
    @DOB datetime
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN

    return case 
    when 
        ( 
            (@DOB >  CONVERT(datetime, '19100101', 102))
            and
            @DOB <  DATEADD(yyyy, -18, getdate())
        )
        then @DOB 
        else null
    end
END
```

then your insert statement should become:

```
INSERT INTO [DBO].[UA_T]
     (
      [DOB],
      [SSN],
      [OCCUPATION],
      [PLACE_OF_ISSUANCE],
      [EXCEPTION_BIT])
VALUES     (
      [dbo].[CheckDate](@DOB),
      @SSN,
      @OCCUPATION,
      @PLACE_OF_ISSUANCE,
      @Exception_Bit)
```

*Note: from your answer I don't understand if you want to get null for people older than 18 or younger than 18. This function returns null for people younger than 18. If you want it the other way just change < with >= in this condition:*  `@DOB <  DATEADD(yyyy, -18, getdate())`